# How to get latest data from database and show on top using RxJava2

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am creating app using MVVM pattern and using retrofit2 and rxjava2 I am fetching data from server and showing it in recycler view.So far data has been fetched successfully in recycler view but data added recently is showing in last position in recycler view.I want to show recently added data on top in recycler view:

This is my code to show data in recycler view:

**Contacts.java**

```
public class Contacts extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
private ContactsAdapter adapter;
private ProgressBar progressBar1;
private ContactViewModel viewModel;


public Contacts() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

    recyclerView=  view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    progressBar1 = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContactViewModel.class);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    adapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity(),contactList);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewModel.getAllContacts().observe(this, new Observer<List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Contact> contacts) {

            progressBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            adapter.setContactList(contacts);
        }
    });

    return view;
  }

}
```

**ContactViewModel.java**

```
public class ContactViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

ContactRepository repo;
MutableLiveData<List<Contact>> mutableLiveData;

public ContactViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);

    repo  = new ContactRepository(application);
    mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
  }

public MutableLiveData<List<Contact>> getAllContacts() {
    return repo.getMutableLiveData();
  }
}
```

**ContactRepository.java**

```
public class ContactRepository {

Context context;
MutableLiveData<List<Contact>> contactmutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

public ContactRepository(Context context){

    this.context = context;
}

public MutableLiveData<List<Contact>> getMutableLiveData() {

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    apiService.getContacts().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Contact>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Contact> contacts) {

                    contactmutableLiveData.setValue(contacts);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    TastyToast.makeText(context,e.getMessage(),TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,TastyToast.ERROR).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });

    return contactmutableLiveData;
  }

}
```

**ContactsAdapter.java**

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

public ContactsAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> contactList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.contactList = contactList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_row,parent,false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

    final String str1 = contact.getFirstname();
    final String str2 = contact.getLastname();

    holder.userName.setText(str1 + " " +str2);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

public void setContactList(List<Contact> contactList) {
    this.contactList = contactList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView userName;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
      }
   }

}
```

**Contact.java**

```
public class Contact {

String firstname,lastname;

public Contact(){

}

public Contact(String firstname,String lastname){

    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;

}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
}
```

Someone please let me know how can I get desired output. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: You have not added any datetime or identifier field based on which you can sort data. Add datetime and sort data in descending order to get latest data.

Comment: what If I fetch date-time from server then how can I will be able to sort latest data on top.

Comment: What do you mean by fetching datetime from server? Are you talking about the time when you make api call?

Comment: yes means what if I save  time also along with name on the server and then fetch name and time in recycler view so using this approach how can I get latest data on top.

Comment: Have you tried sorting the list by timestamp?

Comment: I am not getting an idea of how to implement logic.